# Will people get confused when they see 'Some of our customers speak Spanish, English, and German'?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, ambiguity

> Our cakes are very popular for foreign visitors.
>   Some of them speak Spanish, Some speak English, and some speak German.

Now, I want to make the second sentence neat and more easy to read, so I am writing it this way:

> Some of our customers speak Spanish, English, and German.

But I am afraid that the new sentence will make people think that these   customers speak three languages, (i.e. Spanish, English and German).
Can you give me some advice please?

Comment: In formal logic, the *and* would mean that some of your visitors speak all three languages. Simply use *or* and it means that some of your customers speak one or more of those languages.

Comment: "Our cakes are .... Some of them speak ...." Yeah, talking cakes that speak three languages would *certainly* be popular for foreign visitors! ;-)

Comment: When repeating like this, you can shorten the third one if you have to: _Some of our customers speak Spanish, some speak English, and some,  German._

Comment: It is guaranteed that people will get confused.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just replacing *and* with *or* removes the ambiguity:

> Our cakes are very popular *among* foreign visitors.
>   Some of our customers speak Spanish, English, *or* German.

"Or" would be interpreted in this case to mean "at least one of …".

However, that still doesn't make these two sentences well constructed.  I have a hard time figuring out what connection you are trying to draw between linguistic ability and food preferences.  I suggest combining all of the facts into one statement:

> Our cakes are especially popular among our Spanish-, English-, and German-speaking customers.

That makes it clearer that you are categorizing your customers by inferring their place of origin through their language.  Or, if you wish to to use a simpler and less specific expression, you could, in some contexts, say "western" to mean roughly European / Australian / North American / South American.  (There's no point in being exact, since you are just expressing general preferences anyway.)

> Our cakes are especially popular with our western customers.

Answer (score 4):

> Our cakes are very popular for foreign visitors. 
>   Some of them speak Spanish, [s]ome speak English, and some speak German.

Yes, the revised sentence (*Some of our customers speak Spanish, English, and German*) can be ambiguous. The most natural way to interpret the sentence is that it means

> *Some of our customers* speak all three languages.

However, your original sentence is not difficult or cluttered. Repetition of structure is sometimes good; it allows the reader to anticipate what's ahead in the sentence. It is like taking the hand of the reader and guiding them. So it's not bad.

Note also that *with foreign visitors* is more idiomatic.  See the sentences at  [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/popular).

Comment: Because the cakes are the subject of your first sentence, it makes the second sentence sound like you're saying the cakes speak different languages...

Answer (score 4):

1. I will replace the preposition *for* with *among* (or possibly with) which sounds a little more natural.

> Our cakes are very popular among foreign visitors.

2. Your original sentence doesn't have any problem except that you are repeating the same word.

> They speak English, German and Spanish to name a few.

It doesn't necessarily mean one visitor speaks all three languages. It means you have visitors from all over Europe. Considering the fact that many Europeans (especially travelers) are bi or tri-lingual, I don't think you need to worry about the possibility that the sentence could mean they speak three languages.

Comment: I think "with" would be better than "among." Sounds more natural.

Comment: The sentence **does** claim, that they speak all of those three languages. However, as natural languages are a mess, most people wouldn't interpret this sentence in this correct fashion and instead, falsely, interpret it as intended. On the other hand, I suspect that most people who are aware of the correct interpretation, won't be confused, because this is a very common mistake and common sense indicates the indented meaning.